# How to add a space (margin) under the border of a div? | Confluence Header

Tags: html, css, confluence

I want to create a PDF-Layout for confluence, by using basic html and css.

I have a border-bottom style attribute in a div and I set the padding for the border manually.

How can I add more space below that border?

```css
.fsTitlePage {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 50mm;
  margin-right: auto;
  page-break-after: always;
}

.fsTitle {
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 72px 0 4px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #184b65;
}
```

```html
<div class="fsTitlePage">
  <center>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="" style="width: 350px; height: auto;">         
    <br><br>
    <hr style="border-color: #f39100; width: 100px;">
    <div class="fsTitle">Some<b class="fsTitle">Title</b> Bla Bla</div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is border-bottom in your code? and Please elaborate what exactly you want to acheive

Comment: *I have a border-bottom style attribute in a div *, Which `div` and where's the `property` is written?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So you need a bigger border? If so use this code

```
border: 10px solid #f39100;
```

instead of your code

```
border-color: #f39100;
```